# Error: Could not find or load main class OCI_HelloWorld

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am to new java, ant and to stackoverflow.

I have a build.xml file under Project_Dir director in windows and run "ant run" command to run OCI_HelloWorld.java file which is under "src" folder.

I am getting below error after running "ant run" command.

```
C:\Project_Dir>ant run
Buildfile: C:\Project_Dir\build.xml

run:
     [java] Error: Could not find or load main class OCI_HelloWorld
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Below is my build.xml file

```
<!-- define the classpath for building the project -->
<path id="build.classpath">
    <!-- include jar files under lib directory -->
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
</path>

<!-- define the classpath for running the project -->
<path id="run.classpath">
    <!-- include jar files under lib directory -->
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />

    <!-- include the jar file resulting from building the project -->
    <pathelement path="build/dist/OCI_HelloWorld.jar" />
</path>

<!-- build the jar file for the project -->
<target name="build" description="Build the HelloWorld program">

    <!-- first compile your java class code -->
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" debug="true" includes="C:\Project_Dir\src\*.java" fork="yes" executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac">
        <classpath refid="build.classpath" />
    </javac>

    <!-- now assemble a jar file from the compiled classes -->
    <mkdir dir="build/dist" />
    <jar jarfile="build/dist/OCI_HelloWorld.jar" fork="yes" basedir="build/classes">
        <fileset dir="build/classes" includes="**/*.*" />
    </jar>
</target>

<!-- run the project jar file -->
<target name="run" description="Run the HelloWorld program">
    <!-- run java on the resulting code -->
    <java classname="OCI_HelloWorld" fork="true" >
        <classpath refid="run.classpath" />
    </java>
</target>

<!-- reset build environment to starting point -->
<target name="clean" description="Cleans up your project build artifacts">
    <delete dir="build" />
</target>
```

Please let me know what I need to do to get rid of this error.

Comment: `ant build` needs to run before `ant run`.

Comment: '<C:\Project_Dir>ant build
Buildfile: C:\Project_Dir\build.xml

build:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Project_Dir\build\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Project_Dir\build\dist
      [jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: C:\Project_Dir\build\dist\OCI_HelloWorld.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds>'

Comment: @Chad Nouis ant build was success

Comment: @ChadNouis in debug I see this:

fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Project_Dir\src with patternSet{ includes: [C:\Project_Dir\src\OCI_HelloWorld.java] excludes: [] }
    [javac] No sources found.

[jar] No Implementation-Title set.No Implementation-Version set.No Implementation-Vendor set.
[jar] Location: C:\Project_Dir\build.xml:30:

Comment: please post OCI_HelloWorld class source